# How to implement stored procedure in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Write stored procedure to

1. Insert Product
2. Update Product
3. Select Product
4. Insert Customer
5. Update Customer
6. Select Customer
7. Insert SalesTransaction
8. Update SalesTransaction
9. Select SalesTransaction

How to implement these in Asp.net core using SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 0):

First, Try getting System.Data.Common and System.Data.SqlClient via NuGet. Once you have those references then you can start writing ADO.NET commands in your app:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String Here")){  
    string sql = "YourStoredProcedureName";
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)){
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", "SomeValueHereToPass");
        sqlConn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)){
            sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
}
```